# Kelp build error - go-astilog not loading

Tags: kelp

Happy to join here and appreciate your patience with what may be a basic question. Have been working to follow "Compile from Source" instructions and seem to have all dependencies & astilectron-bundler installed. My build is failing with the following message.

compiling ... build github.com/stellar/kelp: cannot load github.com/asticode/go-astilog: module github.com/asticode/go-astilog@latest found (v2.0.1+incompatible), but does not contain package github.com/asticode/go-astilog                                                                                                                                          build failed with error code 1

I'd greatly appreciate any advice or potential fixes.